# How to send a file to clients using owin httplistener?

Tags: c#, owin, httplistener

I've googled a lot about sending a file from a console application using an own HTTP listener self-hosted to a web application that hosted on ASP.NET MVC5 I've found a method in response named `res.SendFileAsync`, but I don't know how to use it. Here's my code:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
     app.UseHandlerAsync((req, res) =>
    {
        Console.Clear();
        foreach (var item in req.Headers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ":" );
            foreach (var item1 in item.Value)
            {
                Console.Write(item1);
            }
        }
        //res.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
        //result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        //result.Content = new StreamContent(st);
        //result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = st.Length;

        res.Headers.Add("ContentType" ,new string[]{"application/octet-stream"});
         res.SendFileAsync(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\1.mp3");
        // res.ContentType = "text/plain";
         return res.WriteAsync("Hello, World!");
    });
}
```

This is an own startup class that handles HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586733/sending-a-value-from-server-to-client-with-sockets/34669446) which will cover all of your needs, basically to save you time, if you want to send a `byte[]` to all your clients (which is how you should send a file) it should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //---listen at the specified IP and port no.---
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT_NO));
    serverSocket.Listen(4); //the maximum pending client, define as you wish
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);      

    //normally, there isn't anything else needed here
    string result = "";
    do {
        result = Console.ReadLine();
        if (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit") {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            //you can use `result` and change it to `bytes` by any mechanism which you want
            //the mechanism which suits you is probably the hex string to byte[]
            //this is the reason why you may want to list the client sockets
            foreach(Socket socket in clientSockets)
                socket.Send(bytes); //send everything to all clients as bytes
        }
    } while (result.ToLower().Trim() != "exit");
}
```

I'd recommend you to delve deeper into the post and understand the entire process, see if it fits your solution.